# Elements of the range of a random variable that are transformed into the same element

Tags: probability-theory, notation, terminology, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y = g(X)$. Then, the range or support of $Y$ can be written as $R_Y = \{g(x) \mid x \in R_X\}$. My question is whether there is a name (or standard notation) for $$S_y = \{x \in R_X \mid g(x) = y\} \, ,$$ that is, the elements of $R_X$ that, through $g$, give the specified $y$.

Comment: If the domain of $g$ is $R_X$, it's $g^{-1}(\{y\})$. In general it's $g^{-1}(\{y\})\cap R_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is often called the pre-image of $y$. It's perhaps better to define the notion of preimages of SETs, so if $U \subset R_Y$, you write

$$
S_U = \{x \in R_X \mid g(x) \in U \}
$$
and call that the "preimage of $U$". But that means that for a single element $y \in R_Y$, you should really write
$$
S_{\{y\} } = \{x \in R_X \mid g(x) \in \{y\} \}.
$$

But as far as I know, this is rarely done (alas). People like me who sometimes program computers, and have to worry about types, tend to be more obsessive.

By the way, the mapping implicitly defined above, from "subsets of $R_Y$" to "subsets of $R_Y$" is typically denoted by $g^{-1}$, so for a subset $U$ of $R_Y$, we write $g^{-1}(U)$ for the thing I've called $S_U$ above.

That means that for a bijection $g$, we have
$$
g^{-1}( \{y\} )  = \{ g^{-1}(y) \},
$$
where the $g^{-1}$ on the left is the thing I've just defined in the preceding paragraph, and the one on the right is the conventional "inverse function". This is a pretty horrid abuse of notation, but once you realize what's going on, you get over it pretty quickly.